# How would you build a road system that respected nature?

Tags: civil-engineering, design

How would build a road system or transportation system that respected nature with the following constraints:

- No paved roads or less than 10% paved roads
- can’t use gasoline (oil)
- allow nature to thrive and migrant with little to no impact
- food and resources can be bussed in or grown locally to reduce transportation
- it can involve new technology or possible new technology

Why?

I visited somewhere that has 8 lane highways in suburban areas. Eight lanes.... Where I grew up there were two lane or one lane roads. Even then you’d see roadkill daily. Some parts of the city where completely transformed from their natural state that wild life depended on for survival.

I think in the future we will have forest garden type cities or villages with less travel or less harmful travel with respect to nature and plant and animal life.

I’ve seen examples of this in many retro future artworks. But in some of those they still have roads that interrupt nature or flying cars.

What engineering answer would you give if this was your issue to solve?

For example, it doesn't have to be broad. It can be I'd build "mag lev roads for bikes and small vehicles and larger roads outside of cities".

Comment: This question is far too broad for this site. Try Worldbuilding.SE

Comment: @PhilSweet if you put “hover cars” i would accept that. but i may try posting there. let’s see what what

Comment: "Gas" - do mean a gasseous substance such as methane, or the abbreviation North American's use for gasoline/petrol? In limiting it to just "gas" would diesel be okay to use, or do you mean all hydrocarbon based fuels used for vehicles? Also, some of the benefits of paved roads are: less maintenance and no production of dust as vehicles drive along them. What you seem to be wanting is a return to pre 20th Century lifestyles. Without a significant reduction in human population I don't see that happening.

Comment: @Fred i meant gasoline. i mean oil. what we are using in vehicles. yep dust would be issue with fort road. maybe granite or stone roads. or placing a magnetic field under dirt roads so that vehicles can hover above them without kicking up dust.

Comment: I used to work with a chap called Jim McElwaine, some of whose research was motivated by trying to understand what controls the durability of unpaved roads.  You might find it useful to look at some of [his publications](https://scholar.google.co.uk/citations?user=lRnZ93AAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao) (particularly ones with "washboard" in the title).